# how to make this code faster (time limit 0.1 secs)

Tags: java, time, execution

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class pool 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException 
    { 
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in); 
        int t=in.nextInt(); 
        for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
        { 
            int a=in.nextInt(); 
            if ((360.0/(180-a))==Math.round((360.0/(180-a))))
                System.out.println("yes"); 
            else 
                System.out.println("NO"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I declare `t=Integer.MAX_INT`.  How can I possibly guarantee that it will execute in less than a tenth of a second?  (Also, I/O in general is slow - not printing out values and instead populating some external structure to reference them later would be more ideal.)

Comment: This question might be better asked on another [Stack Exchange community](http://stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the call to round and the floating point arithmatic by comparing `360/(180-a)` and `(540-a)/(180-a)`

The floor of `360.0/(180.0-a)+1.0` would be the same as `Math.Round(360.0/(180.0-a)`. With some simple algebra that equals `(540-a)/(180-a)`, which the floor of that value will be the result when integer arithmatic is used.

Granted, this does not guarantee the time limit you posted.